# As per Hinduism, What happens to those who worship Imaginary Gods?

Tags: scripture, gods, worship, bhakti, devatas

As per texts like Bhagavad Gita, Worshippers of Pitrs go to Pitrs and Worshippers of Devas go to Devas in the afterlife. What happens to those who worship Imaginary characters who don't even exist as per scriptures (such as Santoshi Mata) by treating them like an actual diety? Where do they go?

Comment: interesting question.

Comment: I highly doubt it. I don't think there is any word *imaginary* used in Hinduism.